# Find all the constants $a\in\mathbb{R}$ so that the differential equations have solutions in common.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all the constants $a\in\mathbb{R}$ so that the differential equations:
$$(1):y''+ay'-2y=0$$
$$(2):y''-2y'+ay=0$$

have solutions in common.

I think I can get all solutions just by solving the system of the caracteristic polynomials for $\lambda$:
$\begin{align*}
\lambda^2+a\lambda-2 &=0\\
\lambda^2-2\lambda+a &=0
\end{align*}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\begin{align*}
                            \lambda &=\dfrac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}\\
                            \lambda &=\dfrac{2\pm2\sqrt{1-a}}{2}
                            \end{align*}$

 
But then I have to solve for all the case for when the $\pm$ changes so that I have 4 cases $\{(+,+);(+,-);(-,+);(-,-)\}$

This is pretty slow so I was wondering if there was an smarter way to solve for a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that what you mean is **non zero** solutions (because $y=0$ is solution to both differential equations, whatever the value of a).

If $y$ is solution it is also solution of the differential equation obtained by taking the difference of these two equations, i.e.,

$$(a+2)y'=(a+2)y \tag{1}$$

Case 1 : if $a \neq -2$ : one can conclude from (1) that $y$ is such that $y'=y$, i.e.

$$y=Ke^t \    \ \ \ \text{with} \ K \neq 0.\tag{2}$$

Plugging (2) for example in the first equation, one gets

$$Ke^t+aKe^t-2Ke^t=0$$

meaning that $1+a-2=0$, thus solution (2) is possible iff $a=1$.

Case 2 : if, on the contrary, $a=-2$, both initial equations give :

$$y''-2y'-2y=0,$$ and this unique non parametric equation has clearly solutions (that aren't asked).

Thus the answer is :

> There are two values $a=1$ and $a=-2$ satisfying the condition.

Comment: Shouldn't $a=-2$  be a solution as well because then the two differential equations are the same and have solutions in common?

Comment: @Lutzl and Paras Khosla : you are right. Corrected...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.